# Ледовый и ледовитый

Tags: этимология

Интересно, а почему мы говорим, что океан Ледовитый, а не ледовый? Понятно, что название ему было дано давно, когда в языке было много форм слов, которые сейчас не употребляются, но все же я не знаю, чтобы даже тогда была такая форма образования прилагательных.
И есть ли разница между прилагательными "ледовитый" и "ледовый"? Может быть, дело в степени проявления признака?

Answer (score 2):

Суффикс *-овит-(ый)* исторически означал *наделенный чем-то, порождающий что-то*. В современном русском это значение несколько потерялось, но в принце его можно проследить в таких образованиях как *башковитый, мастеровитый, плодовитый* и т.д.  
Сравните *плодовый* и *плодовитый*. У этих слов совершенно разные значения.  
В слове *ядовитый* тот же смысл, при этом значение стало основным, заменив собой *"ядовый", "ядный"*.

*Ледовыитый* используется только в отношении северных морей и океанов, в значении *покрытый льдом*. Это совсем не то же самое, что *ледовый* или *ледяной*.

Comment: Ответ толковый, только суффикс всё же -овит-.

Comment: >Ответ толковый, только суффикс всё же -овит-.  
  
Согласен. Поправил.
Но если уж придираться, то это не один суффикс.

Comment: Тоже согласен.

Answer (score 2):

Ледовитый. Суффикс ОВИТ - достаточно регулярная единица, образующая КАЧЕСТВЕННЫЕ прилагательные со значением склонности к тому, что названо мотивирующим словом: басовитый, домовитый, плодовитый, ядовитый, даровитый.

Ледовый дворец.Суффикс ОВ используется для образования ОТНОСИТЕЛЬНЫХ прилагательных (общее отношение).

Ледяная горка. Суффикс ЯН используется для образования ОТНОСИТЕЛЬНЫХ прилагательных со значением "сделанный, состоящий или предназначенный" для того, что названо существительным.

Answer (score 1):

Есть прилагательное "домовитый", устаревшее "мастеровитый", да и другие наверняка найдутся.
Думаю, речь идёт о некоем "определяющем" признаке. "Ледовой" может быть и шхуна, и обстановка, да и "Ледовый поход", вроде, в истории отмечен. А, вот, "Ледовитый" - только океан.